# Tags are getting replaced after using them

Tags: support, bug, tagging

I just asked a question which was partly about the list of figures. I typed `listof` into the tag-input and both [listoffigures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/listoffigures) and [listoftables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/listoftables) appeared as suggestions. I selected both of them. However, after I posted the question the tags were gone and the unrelated tag [table-of-contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/table-of-contents) had emerged out of thin air.

Is this intended behavior?

It seems like both of these tags are synonyms of [table-of-contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/table-of-contents) which makes little sense on its own IMHO but nevertheless I don't understand why synonymized tags would be suggested at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a bug, but a feature. As you mention, [listoffigures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/listoffigures) and [listoftables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/listoftables) are both [synonyms](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) of [table-of-contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/table-of-contents), and each synonym is replaced by their target when posting. That explains the change after posting.

The reason why the synonyms are suggested during tagging is because initial tags stem from a personal association; you (or whomever writes the question) would not necessarily know about these synonym associations, and would therefore not think that the question should be tagged [table-of-contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/table-of-contents) rather than [listoffigures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/listoffigures) or [listoftables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/listoftables). Providing these suggestions is a way of covering a larger selection of tags that the poster may associate with the post.

Comment: Makes sense. I still think these synonyms are not legitimate. The list of figures will not even show up in the table of contents by default!!

Comment: @leonheess: For [tag:listoffigures] to be a synonym for [tag:table-of-contents] doesn't imply that the LoF is/should be showing in the ToC. It means that these two constructions are very similar in nature - they list internal document elements. And of these, a ToC is most commonly used. Sure, there might be cases where LoF issues are specific to the LoF, but usually solutions to the one have a comparable solution when considering the other (hence them being synonyms)...

Comment: @leonheess: ... Moreover, the [`float` package](//ctan.org/pkg/float) allows the creation of your own `\listof...` and it could be concluded that there should be a need for [tag:listofalgorithms] (created by the [`algorithm` package](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithms), using `float`), or [tag:listofwhatever] for whatever `\listof...` is created (like in [ToC like list of definitions (using theorem environments)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74857/5764)). It's better to use [tag:table-of-contents] and add other appropriate tags that might be relevant.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense to me. However, then it would make more sense to call the tag [list-elements] or similar. The way it is set up rn it is like having a tag called [apple] which is used for all fruits.

Comment: @leonheess: Sure. You could also argue that [tag:table-of-contents] is like [tag:apple] as [tag:listoffigures] is like [tag:apple-fuji], [tag:listoftables] is like [tag:apple-gala], and [tag:listofalgorithms] is like [tag:apple-ambrosia], ... different varieties of the same fruit.

Comment: Well, if list-of-figures is a type of table-of-content it all makes sense. I did not know that.